# How to run psql commands in a PHP script?

Tags: php, postgresql, shell

I need to run some commands which are not part of SQL, eg: `\d` (describe)

One normally runs such commands by first connecting to the database using the psql client, in the command line.

But now I need to do it programatically, using a script. How can I do this? I know about exec(), but psql isn't a normal command. It opens a client in the console, and THEN you run your commands. Kind of like ssh.

Comment: psql *is* a "normal command". It doesn't need a terminal on it's stdin/stdout, and `psql databasename <inputfile >outputfile` works as expected. (but you will need to quote the backslashes at some point(s) )

Answer (score 1):

The -c option solved it.

```
psql [...] -o output.txt -c "\d mytable"
```